# Why does my app behave strangely on Android 13?

Tags: android, canvas, restart, touchscreen, android-13

Do you have any idea what could be the possible causes for the next app strange behavior on Android 13?
Recently (6th January 2023) I published my android game, Focus Pocus, on Google Play. Game link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.JarekApps.FocusPocus
It works as expected on Android versions older than Android 13. It used to work ok also on Android 13, but after last Android 13 software update, android draws a thin white horizontal line at the top of the screen, over my game. It is like a line under the Android notification bar (exactly under the front camera of my Samsung Galaxy A53).
Basically, the game has the portrait screen divided in two: the top half is a canvas and the bottom half is a table arrangement with buttons.
In android 13, the canvas part doesn't work well...if I hold the finger on the image sprite in the canvas (the floating number) while i click the same number on the keyboard, it doesn't work or the sprite is "jumpping" to another position and i lose a life in the game (it should not have this behavior).
The strange thing is that if i restart my phone, THE FIRST TIME when i play the game after the phone restart, it works as expected, but, after i close the game and reopen it, Android 13 makes the changes with the line and the canvas/touch bugs appear.
My game targets API 31
I tested it on another phone with Android 13 (samsung galaxy A51) and it has the same problem.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: FWIW, I have a Samsung Flip 4 with Android 13. I downloaded your game and it runs and looks just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the information provided, potential causes for the issues in your Android game on Android 13 could include compatibility with API changes, canvas and drawing issues, touch input problems, resource handling, lifecycle changes, and device-specific considerations. Use debugging tools and controlled testing to isolate the problem, and consider reaching out to support if needed.